# How to get rid of one navigation bar and merge them as one in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm fairly new to Android. So, please help me with this sily problem
I'm getting two navigation bars. I want to merge the both and get all the elements in one nav bar[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnZxJ.png)
This is my MainActivity

This is my manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".activity.AboutUsActivity"
                android:label="@string/activity_title_about_us" />
            <activity
                android:name=".activity.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
                android:label="@string/activity_title_privacy_policy" />
            <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
                android:label="Main"
                >

            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my app_bar_main.xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:context="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frame"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">            </FrameLayout>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my nav_header_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_header_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_height"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"     />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/website"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my activity_main_drawer.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_home" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_photos"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_photo_library_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_photos" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_movies"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_movies_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_movies" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_notifications"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_notifications" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/nav_settings" />
        </group>

        <item android:title="Other">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
                    android:title="@string/nav_about_us" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
                    android:title="@string/privacy_policy" />
            </menu>
        </item>

    </menu>
```

Original code taken from http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Thank you in advance! :)

Edit
This is my MainActivity.java

```
    package info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.R;
    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.HomeFragment;
    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.MoviesFragment;
    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.NotificationsFragment;
    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.PhotosFragment;
    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.SettingsFragment;
    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.helper.SessionManager;
    import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.other.CircleTransform;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private DrawerLayout drawer;
        private View navHeader;
        private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
        private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private FloatingActionButton fab;

        // urls to load navigation header background image
        // and profile image
        private static final String urlNavHeaderBg =         "http://api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
        private static final String urlProfileImg =         "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eCtE_G34M9ygdkmOpYvCag1vBARCmZwnVS6rS5t4JLzJ6        QgQSBquM0nuTsCpLhYbKljoyS-txg";
        private SessionManager session;
        // index to identify current nav menu item
        public static int navItemIndex = 0;

        // tags used to attach the fragments
        private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
        private static final String TAG_PHOTOS = "photos";
        private static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
        private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
        private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
        public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

        // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
        private String[] activityTitles;

        // flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
        private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
        private Handler mHandler;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            mHandler = new Handler();

            drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

            // Navigation view header
            navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
            txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
            imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView)         navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
            imgProfile = (ImageView)         navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

            // load toolbar titles from string resources
            activityTitles =         getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",          Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

             // load nav menu header data
            loadNavHeader();

            // initializing navigation menu
            setUpNavigationView();

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                navItemIndex = 0;
                CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                loadHomeFragment();
             }
              if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
                 logoutUser();
             }
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LoginActivity",
                     MODE_PRIVATE); String string =          prefs.getString("output",
                     "nothing to display");
          }

        /***
         * Load navigation menu header information
         * like background image, profile image
         * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
           */
         private void loadNavHeader() {
             // name, website
            txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
            txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");

            // loading header background image
            Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

              // Loading profile image
             Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                      .crossFade()
                      .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imgProfile);

            // showing dot next to notifications label
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
         }

        /***
          * Returns respected fragment that user
          * selected from navigation menu
          */
        private void loadHomeFragment() {
            // selecting appropriate nav menu item
            selectNavMenu();

            // set toolbar title
            setToolbarTitle();

            // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do         anything
            // just close the navigation drawer
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG)         != null) {
                 drawer.closeDrawers();

                // show or hide the fab button
                toggleFab();
                return;
             }

            // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
            // when switching between navigation menus
            // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade          effect
            // This effect can be seen in GMail app
             Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // update the main content by replacing fragments
                    Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out);
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment,         CURRENT_TAG);
                    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
             };

            // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
            if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
                mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
            }

            // show or hide the fab button
            toggleFab();

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawer.closeDrawers();

            // refresh toolbar menu
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

         private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
            switch (navItemIndex) {
                case 0:
                    // home
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    return homeFragment;
                case 1:
                    // photos
                    PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
                    return photosFragment;
                case 2:
                    // movies fragment
                    MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
                    return moviesFragment;
                case 3:
                    // notifications fragment
                    NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new          NotificationsFragment();
                    return notificationsFragment;

                case 4:
                    // settings fragment
                    SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new         SettingsFragment();
                     return settingsFragment;
                default:
                    return new HomeFragment();
            }
        }

        private void setToolbarTitle() {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
        }

        private void selectNavMenu() {
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
         }

        private void setUpNavigationView() {
            //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the         item click of the navigation menu
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new         NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                 // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                      //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                         //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                        case R.id.home:
                            navItemIndex = 0;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_photos:
                             navItemIndex = 1;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_movies:
                            navItemIndex = 2;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_notifications:
                            navItemIndex = 3;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_settings:
                            navItemIndex = 4;
                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_about_us:
                            // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,          AboutUsActivity.class));
                            drawer.closeDrawers();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                             // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,          PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                             drawer.closeDrawers();
                             return true;
                         default:
                             navItemIndex = 0;
                    }

                     //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                    if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(false);
                     } else {
                         menuItem.setChecked(true);
                     }
                     menuItem.setChecked(true);

                     loadHomeFragment();

                     return true;
                }
            });


            ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new         ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer,          R.string.closeDrawer) {

                @Override
                 public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as         we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as         we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                }
            };

            //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
             drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

            //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon         wont show up
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
         public void onBackPressed() {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawers();
                return;
            }

            // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
            // when user is in other fragment than home
            if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
                 // checking if user is on other navigation menu
                 // rather than home
                if (navItemIndex != 0) {
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    loadHomeFragment();
                    return;
                }
            }

            super.onBackPressed();
        }

         @Override
         public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is         present.

            // show menu only when home fragment is selected
            if (navItemIndex == 0) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            }

            // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for         notifications
            if (navItemIndex == 3) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
            }
             return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
                logoutUser();
           }

            // user is in notifications fragment
            // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
            if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications         marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

             // user is in notifications fragment
            // and selected 'Clear All'
            if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all         notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        // show or hide the fab
        private void toggleFab() {
            if (navItemIndex == 0)
                fab.show();
            else
                fab.hide();
        }
        private void logoutUser() {
            session.setLogin(false);



            // Launching the login activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),         LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you show java code. the above code never show two navigation drawer

Comment: @jinsLukose I took out the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar from app_bar_main.xml. But, now the Hambuger icon has disappeared with that toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="videoeditor.myapplication.MainActivity"><android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="videoeditor.myapplication.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" /></RelativeLayout>
```

java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

[image]

**you mean this as navigation bar**

if so do put this code in Styles.xml

```
 <resources>
```

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemee.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style></resources>
```

Comment: Nope, still show two nav bars. Anyway, thank you for your help. will keep trying

Comment: can you show the your navigation bar picture that you say two navigation bar appears

Comment: that picture has been uploaded with the code above n the first paragraph

Comment: i have doubt to ask what actually you mean navigation bar. please answer me for above edit

Comment: What I mean is the picture has a actionBar(with home and menu on top right) and a ToolBar (with hamburger icon ) I want to merge them both on top of the app and get the hambuger icon besides Home

Comment: I've uploaded the java code and I've commented setSupportActionBar(toolbar); because it is giving me fatal error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.navigationdrawer/info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead

Comment: I should have searched for this error earlier. Sorry for wasting your time on this silly problem. Got the solution by adding ` <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` to my theme declaration instead of putting it in AppTheme.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an easy step. Don't remove the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` from your layout, instead add the attribute `app:elevation="0dp"` to it. Your final layout will be:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
            ...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```